# How do you change the preferred resolution with xrandr?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution, xrandr

I am cloning my 1920x1080 monitor display to a TV (1366x768) using a splitter device. It works fine except rebooting moves all my icons up on the desktop, forcing them into a space of the lower resolution. With the TV HDMI unplugged, the icons stay in the desired locations, and `xrandr` shows the chosen (marked with the asterisk *) and preferred (marked with the plus +) resolution of 1920x1080.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
<snipped>
```

But with the TV plugged in, `xrandr` shows

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 853mm x 480mm
   1366x768      59.81 +
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Is there a way to set the preferred '+' down to the 1920x1080 line?

Comment: Did you have a chance of testing the solution posted?

Answer (score 3):

(I have EDITed the answer, with a more thorough detail and testing)

There are (at least) two methods to change the preferred mode:

1. Using X11 configuration. A little more contrived than method #2.
2. Using [`xrandr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xrandr). One can make these changes permanent, but "There are two disadvantages to using `.xprofile` for xrandr settings. First, it occurs fairly late in the startup process, so you'll see some resolution resizing during the initial screen draw; in some cases panel windows may resize improperly as a result. Second, as this is a per-user setting, it won't affect the resolutions of other users, nor will it alter the resolution on the login screen." ([source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_commands_in_.xprofile)).

Note that adding modes with one method and setting the active mode with another may not succeed, in particular considering the comment for method #2.

---

### X11 configuration

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/63855/226614) and [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_resolution_changes_in_xorg.conf), I put together file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`.
I am using here Bodhi Linux. The location in Ubuntu is likely `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/<something>.conf`, or adding to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, see [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Permanently_adding_undetected_resolutions), [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Monitor_settings) and [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution).

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Main Monitor"
    Modeline        "1344x744_60.00"   80.75  1344 1408 1544 1744  744 747 757 773 -hsync +vsync
    Modeline        "1344x768_60.00"   84.00  1344 1416 1552 1760  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
    Option          "PreferredMode" "1344x744_60.00"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Primary Screen"
    Device          "VGA [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310]"
    Monitor         "Main Monitor"
    SubSection      "Display"
        Modes           "1344x744_60.00" "1344x768_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "VGA [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310]"
    Driver          "radeon"
EndSection
```

Adapt it with the values you need for the new resolution.

---

### `.xprofile`

I added file `~/.xprofile` containing

```
xrandr --newmode "1344x768_60.00"   84.00  1344 1416 1552 1760  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "1344x744_60.00"   80.75  1344 1408 1544 1744  744 747 757 773 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode LVDS "1344x768_60.00"
xrandr --addmode LVDS "1344x744_60.00"
xrandr --output LVDS --mode "1344x744_60.00" --preferred
```

Adapt it with the values you need for the new resolution.

**Related**:

1. [How to change the preferred mode on xrandr?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670287/how-to-change-the-preferred-mode-on-xrandr)
2. [How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125556/how-can-i-make-xrandr-changes-persist
4. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94734/how-to-modify-the-default-setting-adopted-by-xrandr-when-connecting-an-external
5. [How do I save my new resolution setting with xrandr?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754231/how-do-i-save-my-new-resolution-setting-with-xrandr)
6. [Best place to automatically add mode in xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268678/best-place-to-automatically-add-mode-in-xrandr)
7. [Making xRandR Changes Permanent](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=157564)
8. https://linux.die.net/man/1/cvt
9. https://linux.die.net/man/1/gtf
10. https://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr

Comment: Simply adding it to the xorg.conf worked.  (A little surprised since my system didn't even have an xorg.conf to begin with.)